# grep files and sed replace case insensitive

Tags: regex, macos, sed, grep

I need to replace a fairly varied string that looks like such (Mac OS):

```
DBVARNAME="<anything>"
```

or

```
dbvarname="<anything>"
```

or any other combination of case.

I need to find all occurrences of this in every file and replace it with " " (one blank space).

An entire line would be similar to this:

```
<cfprocparam type="Out" dbvarname="locked" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_CHAR" variable="locked" value="#locked#">
```

I have tried:

```
grep -irl dbvarname web|xargs sed -i '' 's/dbvarname=".*" / /g'
```

I realize that this is case sensitive which is one issue. The other is that there are some occurrences where there is a **trailing comma** after the pattern and I **do NOT want to remove those occurrences.**

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: `sed` does not support case-insensitive matching on OS X.

Comment: `Perl` should work, (eg. `perl -pe 's/(dbvarname=")[^"]*/\1 /i'`)...

Comment: I'm not sure where you mean exactly on the trailing comma, within the quotes?

Comment: dbvarname="<anything>", ... in that case I do not want to replace the occurrence

Comment: I see, then this might work `perl -pe 's/(dbvarname=")([\w]+)("[^,]*"\s)/\1 \3/i' ` ...

Comment: Did that work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> or any other combination of case.

```
[dD][bB][vV][aA][rR][nN][aA][mM][eE]
```

> The other is that there are some occurrences where there is a trailing
>   comma after the pattern and I do NOT want to remove those occurrences.

```
...\([^,]\)/\1/g
```

so, put them together:

```
sed 's/[dD][bB][vV][aA][rR][nN][aA][mM][eE]="[^"]*"\([^,]\)/\1/g'
```